# Express Vector and orientation in a different referencial in C++ with Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Let's say I have three referencials (A,B and C)

[image]

I know the following values:

- the position of B in A (as an Eigen::Vector3d)
- the orientation of B in A (as an Eigen::Quaterniond)
- the position of C in B (as an Eigen::Vector3d)
- the orientation of C in B (as an Eigen::Quaterniond)

How can I find the position and the orientation of A in C with C++ and Eigen?

```
Eigen::Vector3d p_B_in_A = Eigen::Vector3d(...);
Eigen::Quaterniond q_B_in_A = Eigen::Quaterniond(...);
Eigen::Vector3d p_C_in_B = Eigen::Vector3d(...);
Eigen::Quaterniond q_C_in_B = Eigen::Quaterniond(...);

Eigen::Vector3d p_A_in_C = ???
Eigen::Quaterniond q_A_in_C = ???
```

Comment: Are you asking about math, the Eigen API or how to write it in C++?

Comment: How to write it in C++ with Eigen, I'll edit that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question with the following code as an example:

```
Eigen::Affine3d B2A = Eigen::Affine3d::Identity();
B2A.translation() << 2 , -1 , 1;
B2A.linear() << std::sqrt(2)/2,  0, std::sqrt(2)/2,
               -std::sqrt(2)/2,  0, std::sqrt(2)/2,
                        0        , -1,         0;

Eigen::Affine3d C2B = Eigen::Affine3d::Identity();
C2B.translation() << 0, 1, 3*sqrt(2);
C2B.linear() <<  1, 0, 0,
                 0,-1, 0,
                 0, 0,-1;

Eigen::Affine3d A2C = C2B.inverse() * B2A.inverse();
// At this point, the orientation of A in C can be found in
// A2C.linear() as a 3x3 rotation matrix. the position of A 
// in C can be found in A2C.translation() as a Vector3d.
```

B2A represents the position and orientation of B in the A frame. In the same way, C2B represents the position and orientation of B in C. By making the inverse of the two transformation, the position and orientation of A in C can be found. Using the [Affine](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialGeometry.html) from Eigen is really useful to make space transformation and combining translations and rotation.